# Mongo query with sort order returns document in incorrect order

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection with about 600k documents. I'm enumerating the collection, sorted by _id. However, documents are not returned in that sorted order. They seem to be sorted correctly according to the timestamp portion of the ObjectId, but not according to the pid field.

This is the c# code I use to repro this:

```
var cursor = m_collection.FindAll().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("_id"));

ObjectId previous = ObjectId.Empty;

foreach (var document in cursor)
{
    var id = document[IdField].AsObjectId;

    Throw.Assert(id > previous, "Sort order is invalid!");
    previous = id;
}
```

At some point, the assert is triggered. I can see that the new id has the same timestamp as the previous one, but a lower pid.

I would have expected that sorting using {"_id":1} would sort using ALL the components of the ObjectIds, not just timestamp.

Does the server use a different comparison algorithm for ObjectIds than the C# client's ObjectId.CompareTo?

Comment: Is the order same when you query from the MongoDB Shell? I just want to see if it's a driver's issue.

Comment: The order is the same from the MongoDB Shell.

Comment: I found out the problem. The C# drivers stores the ObjectId components as signed integers and uses the default signed comparison. The server sorts using the unsigned representation of the ObjectId. In my case, I sometimes got a case where, for the same timestamp/machine, I had a pid that was "positive" and one that was "negative" (when signed). In that case, signed and unsigned comparison won't give the same results. I would consider this a bug in the C# driver I think.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. Open an issue in their [issue tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa). They are fantastic in resolving the issues.

Answer (score 0):

The source for the MongoDB C# `CompareTo` is currently [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.Bson/ObjectModel/ObjectId.cs#L410). The code compares each element of the `ObjectId` all the way to 3 byte counter. Given the nature of the [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/) containing:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch
- a 3-byte machine identifier
- a 2-byte process id
- and a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value

it doesn't make sense to sort beyond the time stamp. The `CompareTo` while it is accurate and will produce consistent results, may not sort in a manner that matches with your expectations.

Given that there will be instances where two objects were created at the same timestamp (4 byte value), you'll have some variance then in the results given the way that the `CompareTo` in C# works. So, performing assertion you made will result in some confusing results and should not be used as a way of detecting an out of sequence result.

Most drivers create the `_id`/`ObjectId` value when it's not present (including the C# driver). There's really not much you could sort on besides the timestamp.

You could do:

```
Throw.Assert(id.Timestamp > previous.Timestamp, "Sort order is invalid!");
```

Comment: The assert is just a test :). What I actually wanted to do was to process a bunch of documents at a time, each time storing the "last processed _id", from where I can resume afterwards (in another run). This requires that the sorting from the server is reliable. Hopefully the sort is at least coherent with the $gt operator, so I can just use the _id of the last document returned by the sorted query and then use {$gt:last_id} in next query.

Comment: you can definitely do that. the sort on the server is consistent.